# get element from array from response

Tags: arrays, api, go, parsing

I want to get second element from array from an HTTP response, but I don't understand how.

```
        // make GET request
        response, error := http.Get("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=ETHUSDT&interval=5m&limit=5")
        if error != nil {
            fmt.Println(error)
        }
    
        // read response body
        body, error := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    
        if error != nil {
            fmt.Println(error)
        }
    
        // close response body
        response.Body.Close()
    
        // print response body
        fmt.Println(string(body))
```

This is respons:

```
/*

[[1684914900000,"1818.17000000","1818.17000000","1813.82000000","1814.07000000","2252.21430000",1684915199999,

"4088300.51162300",2231,"1056.16450000","1917074.16909000","0"],[1684915200000,"1814.07000000","1816.90000000","1813.35000000",

"1816.76000000","1721.60850000",1684915499999,"3124080.20094500",1984,"1016.47410000","1844514.03018800","0"],

[1684915500000,"1816.76000000","1817.08000000","1815.77000000","1816.66000000","774.00760000",1684915799999,"1405864.36999700",

1349,"382.31660000","694372.58708700","0"],[1684915800000,"1816.67000000","1816.67000000","

1814.43000000","1816.19000000","1390.68620000",1684916099999,"2524716.97451500",1552,"457.95860000","831395.49368900","0"],

[1684916100000,"1816.19000000","1817.08000000","1815.80000000","1817.07000000","536.54530000",1684916399999,"974504.17830700",1047,"312.72070000","568003.96710900","0"]]

*/
```

I want get second item from second Array. Please, help me to parse array and get elements that I need

Answer (score 1):

[Sample Project](https://go.dev/play/p/EDM1Fz02TrA)  tryout this one.JsonResp struct that represents the structure of the JSON response. then it makes the HTTP request, reads and parses the response body, and extracts the second element from the `resp`.

check out the sample project for a better understanding

Answer (score -1):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    response := `[[1684914900000,"1818.17000000","1818.17000000","1813.82000000","1814.07000000","2252.21430000",1684915199999,
"4088300.51162300",2231,"1056.16450000","1917074.16909000","0"],[1684915200000,"1814.07000000","1816.90000000","1813.35000000",
"1816.76000000","1721.60850000",1684915499999,"3124080.20094500",1984,"1016.47410000","1844514.03018800","0"],
[1684915500000,"1816.76000000","1817.08000000","1815.77000000","1816.66000000","774.00760000",1684915799999,"1405864.36999700",
1349,"382.31660000","694372.58708700","0"],[1684915800000,"1816.67000000","1816.67000000","1814.43000000","1816.19000000","1390.68620000",1684916099999,"2524716.97451500",1552,"457.95860000","831395.49368900","0"],
[1684916100000,"1816.19000000","1817.08000000","1815.80000000","1817.07000000","536.54530000",1684916399999,"974504.17830700",1047,"312.72070000","568003.96710900","0"]]
`
    var elements [][]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(response), &elements)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", elements[1][1])
}
```